# Downloaded package won't unzip, installation is broken

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

Something is not well in Ubuntu land. This morning, when upgrading my media PC, "apt" kept segfaulting. After manually downloading and upgrading apt and libapt, I fixed that. I then did `apt update` followed by `apt upgrade -y`. This is the result:

```
...
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-amber-dri_21.3.9-0ubuntu1~22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amber-dri:amd64 (21.3.9-0ubuntu1~22.04.1) over (21.3.7-0ubuntu1
) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): ZSTD_decompressStream error : Corrupted block detected 

dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-amber-dri_21.3.9-0
ubuntu1~22.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so' to 
'/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or 
stream
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of libgl1-amber-dri:amd64, which would be brok
en by installation of libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure libgl1-amber-dri:amd64 (broken by libgl1-mesa-dri:am
d64)
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-dri_23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libgl1-amber-dri:amd64 (21.3.7-0ubuntu1), to allow installation o
f libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1) ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1) over (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.
1~22.04.1) ...
Replacing files in old package libgl1-amber-dri:amd64 (21.3.7-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-amber-dri_21.3.9-0ubuntu1~22.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I deleted the offending .deb file and did `apt --fix-broken install` but I just keep getting the same result.

I manually downloaded, and tried to install, libgl1-amber-dri and it tells me that it depends on "libglapi-mesa (>= 23.0.4)". I tried to manually download that, and after initially getting a broken link message, I succeeded.

The `apt --fix-broken install` then worked.

I would try to submit a bug report, but don't know how or where.

Why is this broken? How did the apt system manage to download what looks like a partial file for that .deb file?

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). The answers to both "*Why is this broken?*" and "*How did the apt system manage to download what looks like a partial file for that .deb file?*" are both in the output you provided.